# Text field custom validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

Hi, I am new to jQuery.

I want a validation that works like this:

If a text field has a specific value, say "Robi", then on submit click event the text field will become empty but any value other than "Robi" will submit the data successfully.

Some suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    return $.trim($("#myInputField").val(function(i, val) {
        return val == "Robi" ? "" : val;
    }).val()) != "";
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2mR8b/

Comment: how can i target a specific text field if i have more than one textfield

Comment: If you want to target a specific text field I think you would use $('#id_of_textfield') instead of $(":text")

Comment: @user1496872 as Kenny mentioned, use IDs and make selection with hash `#` symbol. You can try the DEMO in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type='text' id='name' />
</form>
```

Script:

```
  $("form").on("submit", function() {
       var name = $("#name").val();
       if(name == "Robi"){
           $("#name").val("");
           return false;
        }
       else{
            // continue to submit
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="txtfield" value="" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#myform').submit(function() {
      if ($('#txtfield').val() == "Robi") { $('txtfield').val(''); return false; }
   });

});
```